# MySQL table update after multi field check

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, where-clause

Hi I have two table one like this one:
table1
[image]

and one like this:
table2

[image]

I would like to update all the fields on the table2  column "newID"  based on this rules: if  (table2.ID = table1.ID_actual or table2.ID=table1.ID_old) then table2.newID = table1.newID
How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join of the 2 tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.ID IN (t1.ID_actual, t1.ID_old)
SET t2.newID = t1.newID
```